# Limit aggregation feed to return when activity_count is greater than N

Tags: getstream-io

Imagine we have 2 verbs, **posted** and **listened**, added to a flat feed. Then we have an aggregated feed following that flat feed. Lets say we base our aggregation rules on time and we have 5 activityGroups so far:

```
[0] verb: listened, activityCount: 3
[1] verb: posted,   activityCount: 1,
[2] verb: listened, activityCount: 1,
[3] verb: listened, activityCount: 2,
[4] verb: posted,   activityCount: 1,
```

My question is:
**Is it possible to remove the listened verb activityGroup until they hit a threshold for instance greater than 2?**
The result would have me seeing the aggregated feed like this:

```
[0] verb: listened, activityCount: 3
[1] verb: posted,   activityCount: 1,
[2] verb: posted,   activityCount: 1,
```

The reason I'd like the service and not my server or client to handle this is because I want to preserve the pagination that stream supplies.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to get that functionality with an aggregation template, because the template can only take into account the single activity which is being added, not all the activities which belong to the same group. The fields available are described in https://getstream.io/docs/#aggregated-feeds in the Aggregation Format Syntax section. Also check-out https://getstream.io/blog/aggregated-feeds-demystified/ for some inspiration.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think this was possible but was hoping I missed something. Appreciate the the links especially the second one.